# Javascript not working on Modal

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, jquery-mobile

I'm have a hybrid BlackBerry/IOS app in JQuery Mobile. I have two JavaScript functions, one to fill a drop down box and one to fill a text box depending on the value selected in said drop down via onChange.

Both are working perfectly in BlackBerry, none are working in IOS. To fill the DropDown I'm calling the function where the page selected in jQuery, however, in IOS it doesn't call another page but rather a modal window. I tried calling the function before calling the modal, while calling the modal, after calling the modal. Nothing.

How, or where, can I execute the function when the modal loads?

Also, even if I hard code options in the drop down box, the function in onChange is not executed? Is there a particular way to use JavaScript while in a modal window?

Thanks!

Comment: I dont know answer but may i know how you use javascript to display dropdown in ios...can you give me sample code...

Comment: The dropdown is there, regular HTML, what I'm doing is adding options:
mySelect = $('#dropdownID');

myOptions = {
 1: 'Selection One',
 2: 'Selection Two'
 }

$.each(myOptions, function (val, text) {
 mySelect.append(
 $('<option></option>').val(val).html(text)
 );
});

Comment: ok so you used drop down with html code...